# How to select table with a concatenated column?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have the following data:

```
select * from art_skills_table;
+----+------+---------------------------+
| ID | Name | skills                    | 
+----+------+---------------------------|
|  1 | Anna | ["painting","photography"]| 
|  2 | Bob  | ["drawing","sculpting"]   |
|  3 | Cat  | ["pastel"]                |
+----+------+---------------------------+

select * from computer_table;
+------+------+-------------------------+
| ID   | Name | skills                  |  
+------+------+-------------------------+
|    1 | Anna |   ["word","typing"]     |
|    2 | Cat  |   ["code","editing"]    |
|    3 | Bob  |   ["excel","code"]      |
+------+------+-------------------------+
```

I would like to write an SQL statement which results in the following table.

```
+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| ID   | Name | skills                                        |  
+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | Anna |   ["painting","photography","word","typing"]  |
|    2 | Bob  |   ["drawing","sculpting","excel","code"]      |
|    3 | Cat  |   ["pastel","code","editing"]                 |
+------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried something like `SELECT * from art_skills_table LEFT JOIN computer_table ON name`. However it doesn't give what I need. I've read about `array_cat` but I'm having a bit of trouble implementing it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying a Left join here?  Is the art_skill_table priority over the computer_table?

Comment: The reason why I tried left join is that only the skills column matter from the computer_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the skills column from both tables are arrays, then you should be able to get away with this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, array_cat(a.skills, c.skills)
FROM art_skills_table a LEFT JOIN computer_table c 
ON c.id = a.id
```

That said, While you used LEFT join in your sample, I think either an INNER or FULL (OUTER) join might serve you better.

Answer (score 0):

First, i wondered why the data are stored in such a model.
Was of the opinion that NoSQL databases lack ability for joins and ...

- ... a semantic triple would be in the form of subject–predicate–object.
- ... a Key-value (KV) stores use associative arrays.
- ... a relational database would be normalized.

A few information about the use case would have helped.

Nevertheless, you can select the data with `CONCAT` and `REPLACE` for the desired form.

```
SELECT art_skills_table.ID, computer_table.name, 
CONCAT(
  REPLACE(art_skills_table.skills, '}',','), 
  REPLACE(computer_table.skills, '{','')
)
FROM art_skills_table JOIN computer_table ON art_skills_table.ID = computer_table.ID
```

The query returns the following result:

```
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
| ID | Name |                   Skills                   |
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Anna | {"painting","photography","word","typing"} |
|  2 | Cat  | {"drawing","sculpting","code","editing"}   |
|  3 | Bob  | {"pastel","excel","code"}                  |
+----+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I've used the ID for the JOIN, even though Bob has different values. 
The JOIN should probably be done over the name.

```
JOIN computer_table ON art_skills_table.Name = computer_table.Name
```

BTW, you need to tell us what SQL engine you're running on.